# How to know what life is?

Tags: idealism, life, meaning-of-life

What we call ‘our life’ is about a period of time from birth to death. During that period, some might like to devote themselves to certain virtues, some to the religions-promised afterlife, some to an ideology like communism or nazism.

But there are also others who believe such things to be anti-life. Instead, they take life to be about concrete everyday things, such as eating good food, having relationship, to love and being loved, etc.

What is life? How to understand it? I would like to know the views of fellow philosophers.

Comment: Life is what you make of it. Each to his or hers own preferences.

Comment: This is a really open-ended and really unanswerable question. try asking a more specific question and I'm sure people could help. What guides your life is exactly what a philosophy is, so the answer to this question is really whatever philosophy you decide to follow or create.

Comment: This entry on [The Meaning of Life](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/life-meaning/) in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy might be a good place to begin your exploration.

Answer (score 1):

Life is experiences. Experiences as in feelings.

As long as one has ability to feel he is alive. If something cannot feel he is not alive.

Note that its about ability to feel. One is still alive when unconscious. Its because he is not dead, he didn't loose the ability to feel.

Can a dead body feel anything? Our observations show it don't. Pin it, punch it, burn it, no reaction. Ofcourse we are limited to our observations and to whats told to us if whats told is indeed right.

Muslims are told that though once we are dead we dont feel this worldly things we do feel other things. Pleasures and pains that depends only on our deeds and on God's mercy. The grave part of Life After Death that happens to everybody even if they dont get a physical grave.

Is a stone alive? None of our observations show it is. If your religion says it is only then you will believe it is alive.

In every day speak we say a person is lively if that person is having a lot of experiences in his life. An olympics player, a world traveller, a rock-climber is considered more lively than a regular person.

We say someone's eyes are lively when they show lots of emotions. We "see" a lot going on in that person through his eyes.

Kids are considered more lively than their grandfathers. Kids shows more actions and more emotions. Kids cry, laugh and love without filters.

Answer (score 1):

Life (a meme I found, floating around in cyberspace)

1. Birth
2. WTF!?
3. Death

Well, here's how I feel about life. We're supposed to get from point A (birth) to point B (death). It's a vast ocean and you can either skim on the surface and do it, like a (normal) *ship* or you can go *submarine*, dive, deep as possible, and check what's under the hood in a manner of speaking. The choice ... is *yours* mon ami! You can even *fly* from A to B if you so desire. A metaphor, I hope a good metaphor.